# Is this some fungus?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

This is one of the leaves of my neon pothos. It's been turning brown since past 2-3 days. This is the only leaf showing this particular issue. Will the  brown wilting continue in the entire branch or will it stop where the leaf ends? What is the cause? Thank you.[image]

Comment: A small trick: for fungus do always photos on the two sides. On one side it is often more easy to identify. I think it is just rot

Comment: Thanks. The other side of the leaf doesn't have anything else except the wilting. Will the rot continue in the whole branch? How do i stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common word for the leaf in your photo is leaf "**necrosis**". But, that word only means that the leaf tissue has died. It is not possible to determine exactly what caused it. It might be caused by many things - heat, cold, too much light, too little light, dryness of the air, one of many diseases, or just plain "old age" to name a few. You should notice that the leaf is white and lacks any chlorophyll, so the leaf itself does not contribute any energy to the plant. The plant may be simply allowing it to die away.

It is unsightly and the best thing to do would be to remove the leaf. That would make the plant look better and prevent any unknown diseases (if responsible) from spreading further.

https://homeguides.sfgate.com/necrosis-plant-diseases-39504.html